# renderd rendering tiles only in [6 - 9] zoom range

Tags: openstreetmap

I recently installed an OSM tile server using [these instructions](https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/building-a-tile-server-from-packages/).
Everything works fine except that tiles are only rendered with a zoom between 6 and 9, outside of this range I've pink tiles.

- in /etc/renderd.conf min and max zoom are set to respectively 6 and 19 and
- in the stylesheet to 0-20.
  Can these settings be coded somewhere else? (i don't have a /usr/local/etc/renderd.conf file)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, my bad, I set these settings for debugging purpose, i had to **restart apache** for applying the new settings.